# how to install gcc in arago project embedded linux?

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, yocto, arago

everyone.
I am currently using a **phycore am65x** embedded board. I'm a student, and I don't know much because it's my first time dealing with Embedded. So I need your help. As mentioned earlier, the phycore am65x board does not cover packages. It turned out that it was an **arago project (yocto)** and **apt-get** didn't work. **The problem I am trying to solve is that the goal is to install gcc on the board and compile c on the board** (error erasing gcc). How can I fix this? I need your help.

#### Reference

- uname -a: Linux am65xx-phycore-kit 4.14.79-g9d8d0716d0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 10 17:37:42 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
- cat /etc/issue:

  Arago Project http://arago-project.org \n \l
  Arago 2018.10 \n \l
  PHYTEC: BSP-Yocto-TISDK-AM65xx-ALPHA1

Comment: When using Yocto to build the image, it's the goal *not* to compile on the target.  So you don't need gcc on the image that will be installed on the target.  You do the compilation on the host.  Phytec does have a good manual how to get started with Yocto on there boards.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I was worried about what to do if I had to use gcc inside the embedded board. We have installed gcc so that it works normally. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly simple to install gcc in any linux distribution. Go to this site, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC download the tar and install it according the instructions on the same site. Alternatively, if you have access to the Yocto project and can bitbake it again you can add to the local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append= " libgcc"
```

or something similar.

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I downloaded gcc-linaro-7.5-2019.12.tar and installed gcc. We could see that gcc -version has become a normal recognition. Thank you again for your help.